# disable on condition angular table

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a table in my html file
how do I disable onClick function on condition startdate> currentdate

```
        <ng-container matColumnDef="d">
          <th
            mat-header-cell
            *matHeaderCellDef
          >
            Start Date
          </th>
          <td
            mat-cell
            *matCellDef="let w"
            (click)="display = false; create(false, w)"
            title="Cannot start"
          >
            {{ w.startDate }}
          </td>
        </ng-container>
```

and suppose I want to show "cannot start" title only when startdate>current date
how could I do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a condition in your click logic

.html

```
(click)="clicked(w)"
[attr.title]="isFuture(w) ? 'Cannot start' : 'Can start'"
```

.ts

```
clicked(w) {
    if (this.isFuture(w)) {
        this.display = false;
        this.create(false, w)
    }
}
isFuture(w) {
    return w.startdate > new Date();
}
```

Comment: yes thanks, could you please help with another condition, I updated the question..and suppose I want to show "cannot start" title only when startdate>current date
how could I do that on hover